# Junit Assertions.assertThrows works, but ExpectedException doesn't

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Using assertThrows to test that an exception is thrown works, but I also want to test the exception message using ExpectedException, but it doesnt work even using the same exception, why?

working code:

```
@Test
void test() {
    Assertions.assertThrows(
                MyCustomException.class,
                () -> methodBeingTested()); // passes
}
```

code with problems:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
void test() {
    expectedException.expect(MyCustomException.class);
    methodBeingTested(); // fails
}
```

logs:

```
package.MyCustomException: message.

    at [...]
Caused by: anotherPackage.AnotherException: Exception Message
    at [...]
    ... 68 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Which JUnit version are you using for the test with the `ExpectedException`? I ask because `@Rule` and `ExpectedException` are part of JUnit 4, but when you annotate your test with `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` then the test will be executed by JUnit 5 and JUnit 5 doesn't know how to process `@Rule` annotations...

Comment: Hmm, it seems I'm running with junit 5... Thanks

Comment: In which case, use [`Assertions.assertThrows(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)).

Comment: I'm now using he assertThrows followed by another assertion to test the returned message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thomas pointed in comments, I was using two different versions of JUnit (4 and 5) which doesn't work togheter as I wanted.

My solution was to use assertThrows, assign it to a variable and the assert the message on that variable, relying only on JUnit5

```
Exception exception = assertThrows(
                MyException.class,
                () -> myMethod());

assertEquals("exception message", exception.getMessage());
```

Comment: If you're interested, you can also use a fluent-API library such as AssertJ, which would let you do something like `assertExceptionOfType(MyException.class).isThrownBy(() -> myMethod()).withMessage("exception message");`.

Comment: Refactoring is not viable in this project since it's a monolith used by multiple teams which already use junit and mockito only, but I will definetely use it in the future, much more readable imo, thanks